# Can a shared snack schedule be configured in google docs?

Tags: google-docs

I would like to share a spreadsheet with several contacts - these contacts are parents of kids on my soccer team.

The spreadsheet should have one column with a fixed list of dates, the second column is a parents first and last name.

The purpose is for parents to volunteer a week to provide kids with snacks at half time.

Is there a way I can share this spreadsheet with all parents online, with the following features / behavior:

1. rows with dates in the past cannot be modified by any parent, except me (administrator role)
2. a parent can select only one week to volunteer for.
3. a parent can clear their own contact entry, and re-enter as in 2.

Comment: I suggest looking for a purpose-built tool for this. [Signup Genius](http://signupgenius.com) is one I've used for similar things.

Answer (score 0):

Easier way to do this: Share a calendar. Let the parents know "first come first served". Have them send you a couple of dates so if they can't get one you can apply the second date for them. Then add to the calendar. Permissions can get pretty tricky especially when it comes down to certain rows or columns.